# A is a $n\times n$ matrix , define $A_1=A$, $A_{k+1}=A(A_k+p_kI)$,$p_k=-\frac {tr(A_k)}{k}$, $I$ is the unit matrix. Prove that $A_{n+1}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Give a recursive sequence of matrix: $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix , define $A_1=A$, $A_{k+1}= A(A_k+p_kI)$,$p_k=-\frac {tr(A_k)}{k}$, $I$ is the unit matrix. Prove that $A_{n+1}=0$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I have solved this problem,I'll post my answer later

Comment: I think there is typo since it is false, just take A={{2, 1}, {-1, 3}}

Comment: You may made some calculation mistakes.Actually A={{2,1},{-1,3}} satisfies the conclusion of this question.

Answer (score 1):

$A_k=A(A_{k-1}+p_{k-1}I)=AA_{k-1}+p_{k-1}A=A^2(A_{k-2}+p_{k-2}I)+p_{k-1}A\\=\cdots=A^k+p_1A^{k-1}+\cdots+p_{k-1}A$$f(\lambda)=\lambda^{n+1}+p_1\lambda^n+\cdots+p_n\lambda\Rightarrow$$A_{n+1}=f(A)$

Let the eigenvalues of $A$ to be $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$,so $$p_1=-tr(A)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i$$$$p_2=-\frac{1}{2}tr(A^2-tr(A)A)=\frac{1}{2}[(tr(A))^2-tr(A^2)]\\=\frac{1}{2}[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^2]=\sum_{1\leq\ell_1<\ell_2\leq n}\lambda_{\ell_1}\lambda_{\ell_2}$$

By using Newton formula,we can easily calculate that $$p_k=( -1 )^k\sum_{1\leq\ell_1<\ell_2<\cdots<\ell_k\leq n}\lambda_{\ell_1}\lambda_{\ell_2}\cdots\lambda_{\ell_k}$$So that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $g(\lambda)=\lambda^n+p_1\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+p_n$$\Rightarrow$ $f(\lambda)=\lambda g(\lambda)$

By Hamilton-Cayley theorem,we have $g(A)=0$$\Rightarrow$$A_{n+1}=f(A)=Ag(A)=0\Rightarrow A_{n+1}=0$

Comment: I'm poor in LaTeX,so the layout may be a bit strange.